# How to refresh all rows of grid after inline editing/creating [kendo ui] for asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have nested grids. Inner grid allows inline editing. In special cases after creating new element (row in table) in inner grid, other row of inner grid should be changed. I change that row in database but I dont know how to refresh inner grid. If user press "refresh button" of the grid the data will be shown. How to make inner grid refreshing after adding/editing elements?

Outer grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Portal2.Areas.ResourceGrouping.Models.TruckTrailerDriverViewModel>()
  .Name("TruckGrid")
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
      .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.Id))
        .Read(read => read.Action("JsonTruckTrailerDriverRead", "TrucksGrouping"))
   )
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(x => x.TruckRegNum);
      columns.Bound(x => x.TrailerStartDate);
      columns.Bound(x => x.TrailerEndDate);
      columns.Bound(x => x.TrailerRegNum);
      columns.Bound(x => x.DriverStartDate);
      columns.Bound(x => x.DriverEndDate);
      columns.Bound(x => x.DriverName);
  })
  .Pageable(p => p
      .Refresh(true)
      .PageSizes(true)
      .ButtonCount(5)
      .PageSizes(new[] { 20, 30, 40, 50, 100 }))
  .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
  .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
  .Events(events => events
      .DetailExpand("detailExpand")
      )
  .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
)
```

Template

```
<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
      .Name("tabStrip_#=Id#")
      .SelectedIndex(0)
      .Animation(animation => animation.Open(open => open.Expand(ExpandDirection.Vertical)))
      .Items(items =>
      {
          items.Add().Text("Прицепы").Content(@<text> @TruckTrailer() </text>);
          items.Add().Text("Экипажи").Content(@<text> @TruckDriver() </text>);
      })
                        .ToClientTemplate()
)
```

Inner grid

```
    @helper  TruckTrailer()
{
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Portal2.Areas.ResourceGrouping.Models.CouplerViewModel>()
            .Name("grid_trailers_#=Id#")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(col => col.TruckRegNum);
                columns.Bound(col => col.TrailerRegNum).EditorTemplateName("TrailerTemplateEditor").Width(100);
                columns.Bound(col => col.StartDate).EditorTemplateName("DateTimeEditor").Width(200);
                columns.Bound(col => col.EndDate).EditorTemplateName("DateTimeEditor").Width(200);
                columns.Command(c => c.Edit());
                columns.Command(c => c.Destroy());

            })
            .Sortable()
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
            .ToolBar(toolbar => { toolbar.Create(); })
            .DataSource(data => data
                .Ajax()
                .Sort(sort => sort.Add("StartDate").Descending())
                .Events(events =>
                {
                    events.Error("error_handler");
                })
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(m => m.Id);
                })
                //required: назвать поле именем, отличным от TruckId (например OwnerTruckId), иначе кендо отказываетсая работать
                .Create(update => update.Action("JsonCouplerCreate", "TrucksGrouping", new { OwnerTruckId = "#= Id #" }))
                .Read(read => read.Action("JsonCouplerRead", "TrucksGrouping", new { TruckId = "#= Id #" }))
                .Update(update => update.Action("JsonCouplerUpdate", "TrucksGrouping"))
                .Destroy(update => update.Action("JsonCouplerDestroy", "TrucksGrouping"))
            )
            .Pageable(pager => pager.Refresh(true))
            .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu))
            .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
            .ToClientTemplate()
    )
}
```

Controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult JsonCouplerCreate([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, CouplerNewViewModel model)
    {
        Guid newItemId = Guid.Empty;
        if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            newItemId = TrucksGroupingUtility.Create(model, User.Identity.Name);

            var jsonContactsCreate = Json(GetSingleCouplerViewModel(newItemId).ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
            return jsonContactsCreate;
        }

        return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));

    }
```

If i missed some nessesary code to understand my problem pls write here in comments - i will add

Comment: You must place an event listener on the inner grid for `Save` and then, in your corresponding javascript function, refresh the grid

Comment: Chiappa, i dont know why, but event listeners for each event of inner grid were fired when i expand details of outer grid. (i checked it with alerts)

Answer (score 1):

Solution: add event listener to datasource of inner grid

```
.Events(events => events.Error("error_handler").Sync("sync_handler"))



 function sync_handler(e) {
   this.read();
}
```